# How to parse through a list of lists and analyze the elements together to see how many times they occur over time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, binary

Let's say I have a machine that sends out 4 bits every second and I want to see the amount of times a certain bit signature is sent over time.

I am given an input list of lists that contain a message in bits that change over time.

For my output I would like a list of dictionaries, per bit pair, containing the unique bit pair as the key and the times it appears as the value.

Edit New Example:

For example this following data set would be a representation of that data.  With the horizontal axis being bit position and the vertical axis being samples over time. So for the following example I have 4 total bits and 6 total samples.

```py
a = [
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

For this data set I am trying to get a count of how many times a certain bit string occurs this length should be able to vary but for this example let's say I am doing 2 bits at a time.

So the first sample [0,0,1,1] would be split into this
[00,01,11] and the second would be [01,11,11] and the third would be [11,11,11] and so on. Producing a list like so:

```py
y = [
    [00,01,11],
    [01,11,11],
    [11,11,11],
    [11,11,11],
    [00,00,00],
    [10,01,10]]
```

From this I want to be able to count each unique signature and to produce a dictionary with keys corresponding to the signature and values to the counts.

The dictionary would like this

```py
z = [
    {'00':2, '01':1, '11':2, '10':1}, 
    {'00':1, '01':2, '11':3},
    {'00':1, '11':4], '10':1}]
```

Finding the counts is easy if a have a list of parsed items. However getting from the raw data to that parsed list is where I am currently having some trouble. I have an implementation but it's essentially 3 for loops and it runs really slow over large dataset. Surely there is a better and more pythonic way to get about this?

I am using numpy for some additional calculation later on in my program so I would not be against using it here.

UPDATE:
I have been looking around at other things and came to this. Not sure if this is the best solution either.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1]])

my_list = a.astype(str).tolist()


# How many elements each
# list should have
n = 2

# using list comprehension
final = [([''.join(c[i:(i) + n]) for i in range((len(c) + n) // n)]) for c in my_list]

final = [['00', '01', '11'], ['01', '11', '11'], ['11', '11', '11']]
```

UPDATE 2:

I have ran the following implementations and tested there speeds and here is what I have came up with.

Running the data on the small example of 4 bits and 4 samples with a width of 2.

```py
x = [
    [0,0,1,1],
    [0,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1]]
```

- My implementation took **0.0003 seconds**
- Kasrâmvd's implementation took **0.0002 seconds**
- Chris' implementation took **0.0002 seconds**
- Paul's implementation took **0.0243 seconds**

However when running against an actual dataset of 64 bits and 23,497 samples with a width of 2. I got these results:

- My implementation took **1.5302 seconds**
- Kasrâmvd's implementation took **0.3913 seconds**
- Chris' Implementation took **2.0802 seconds**
- Paul's implementation took **0.0204 seconds**

Comment: What is the max number of bits per pattern in real problem (Corresponding to 2 in example)?

Comment: @PaulPanzer the max number of bits per message would be 64, I would commonly see 8 bits per pattern but it could be at most 64.

Comment: I can do up to 53. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @PaulPanzer do you know why on a smaller dataset FFT performs worse? Obviously it works better on data sets that I am actually working with but it seemed interesting that it did better with more data.

Comment: Probably overheads. convolution needs a certain size to really profit from fft and below that I guess it doesn't offset the cost of the more complicated algo. Btw. I think I fixed the row vs col error, care to take the code for another spin?

Comment: That makes sense. Also the new implementation is great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using convolution. As fast convolution depends on FFT and therefore needs to do computations with floats, we have 52 bits mantissa and 53 is the maximum pattern length we can handle.

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as ss

MAX_BITS = np.finfo(float).nmant + 1

def sliding_window(data, width, return_keys=True, return_dict=True, prune_empty=True):
    n, m = data.shape
    if width > MAX_BITS:
        raise ValueError(f"max window width is {MAX_BITS}")
    patterns = ss.convolve(data, 1<<np.arange(width)[None], 'valid', 'auto').astype(int)
    patterns += np.arange(m-width+1)*(1<<width)
    cnts = np.bincount(patterns.ravel(), None, (m-width+1)*(1<<width)).reshape(m-width+1,-1)
    if return_keys or return_dict:
        keys = np.array([*map("".join, it.product(*width*("01",)))], 'S')
        if return_dict:
            dt = np.dtype([('key', f'S{width}'), ('value', int)])
            aux = np.empty(cnts.shape, dt)
            aux['value'] = cnts
            aux['key'] = keys
            if prune_empty:
                i,j = np.where(cnts)
                return [*map(dict, np.split(aux[i,j],
                                            i.searchsorted(np.arange(1,m-width+1))))]
            return [*map(dict, aux.tolist())]
        return keys, cnts
    return cnts

example = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10,10))
print(example)
print(sliding_window(example,3))
```

Sample run:

```
[[0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0]]
[{b'000': 1, b'001': 3, b'010': 1, b'011': 2, b'101': 1, b'110': 1, b'111': 1}, {b'000': 1, b'010': 2, b'011': 2, b'100': 2, b'111': 3}, {b'000': 2, b'001': 1, b'101': 2, b'110': 4, b'111': 1}, {b'001': 2, b'010': 1, b'011': 2, b'101': 4, b'110': 1}, {b'010': 2, b'011': 4, b'100': 2, b'111': 2}, {b'000': 1, b'001': 1, b'100': 1, b'101': 1, b'110': 4, b'111': 2}, {b'001': 2, b'010': 2, b'100': 2, b'101': 2, b'111': 2}, {b'000': 1, b'001': 1, b'010': 2, b'011': 2, b'100': 1, b'101': 1, b'111': 2}]
```

Comment: I just realized the data being returning is not correct. So for this example below the return data, with a width of 2, should be


a = np.array([
        [0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0]])

output = [{'00': 2, '01': 1, '11': 2, '10': 1}, 
 {'00': 1, '01': 2, '11': 3},
 {'00': 1, '11': 4, '10': 1}]

It should be looking down the columns and pairing iterations together. Also sorry for the poor formatting...

Comment: @JordanSosnowski ah, my bad. I'm looking down rows. Give me a few minutes to fix this.

Comment: That new implementation works perfectly! Thanks so much. Sorry for not being clear enough the first run!

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't pair the bits, but gives them as tuples (although that should be simple enough to do).

EDIT: formed strings of bits as needed.

```
from collections import Counter

x = [[0,0,1,1],
      [0,1,1,1],
      [1,1,1,1]]



y = [[''.join(map(str, ref[j:j+2])) for j in range(len(x[0])-1)] \
     for ref in x]

for bit in y:
    d = Counter(bit)
    print(d)
```

Prints

```
Counter({'00': 1, '01': 1, '11': 1})
Counter({'11': 2, '01': 1})
Counter({'11': 3})
```

EDIT: To increase the window from 2 to 3, you might add this to your code:

```
window = 3
offset = window - 1

y = [[''.join(map(str, ref[j:j+window])) for j in range(len(x[0])-offset)] \
     for ref in x]
```

Comment: That look's great! Definitely more readable that what I came up with. Do you know how well. If I wanted to do bits of 3 length would I change the `j:j+2` to `j:j+3`?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna have a geometrical or algebraic analysis/solution you can do the following:

```
In [108]: x = np.array([[0,0,1,1],
     ...:       [0,1,1,1],
     ...:       [1,1,1,1]])
     ...:       

In [109]: 

In [109]: pairs = np.dstack((x[:, :-1], x[:, 1:]))

In [110]: x, y, z = pairs.shape

In [111]: uniques
Out[111]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1]])

In [112]: uniques = np.unique(pairs.reshape(x*y, z), axis=0)

# None: 3d broadcasting is not recommended in any situation, please read doc for more details,
In [113]: R = (uniques[:,None][:,None,:] == pairs).all(3).sum(-1)

In [114]: R
Out[114]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

The columns of matrix `R` stand for the count of each unique pair in `uniques` object in each row of your original array.

You can then get a Python object like what you want as following:

```
In [116]: [{tuple(i): j for i,j in zip(uniques, i) if j} for i in R.T]
Out[116]: [{(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 1, (1, 1): 1}, {(0, 1): 1, (1, 1): 2}, {(1, 1): 3}]
```

Comment: That looks great! Would it be easy to increase the bit length from 2 with your implementation? For example if I wanted 8 bits length instead?

Comment: @JordanSosnowski Of course. In that case you're just stretching your array along the the third axis. If your problem becomes more than 3D then NO! Broadcasting will have a very large overhead.